# Existence of idempotents versus existence of projections in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be any C*-algebra.
Suppose $x\in\mathcal{A}$ is idempotent, with $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq 1$. Does it follow that $\mathcal{A}$ admits nontrivial projections?

Clearly, when $x$ is normal, $x^*x$ is self-adjoint and idempotent, so that settles the matter. I didn't manage to prove the claim in the general case, though.

(for good measure: a projection is a self-adjoint idempotent element of $\mathcal{A}$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a unital C*-algebra, every idempotent element is similar to a projection in the algebra.  If $e$ is an idempotent element, then $p=ee^*(1+(e-e^*)(e^*-e))^{-1}$ is a projection in the C*-algebra generated by $1$ and $e$, and it is similar to $e$.

For more information see the MathOverflow question [Reference needed for: every idempotent in a C*-algebra is similar to a hermitian one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16943).  In the question a method that would lead to finding $p$ is outlined.  In the answer are further references to this result and generalizations.